# What's difference between initing a structure in main() and in a user-defined function?

Tags: c

fellows.I'm new in C language and today i met a question.I want you guys to help me out of the trouble.

```
struct node {
    int a;
};
void
init_structure(struct node *c)
{
    c=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    c->a=1;
}
int main(){
    struct node *ss;
    init_structure(ss);
    printf("%d\n",ss->a);
}
```

I compile this segment codes with gcc,and no error reporteed.But the answer after i run the ./a.out is **11873660**(i guess maybe it's a address number) while not **1** which is what i want.

I'll be waiting online.

Thank  u fellows :)

Answer (score 5):

`init_structure` is allocating and initializing the structure just fine, but in C, the argument is passed by value (not by reference), so while `c` is changed, `ss` is not changed with it. You can instead return `c` and assign `ss` using the return value:

```
struct node *init_structure(void)
{
    struct node *c=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    c->a=1;
    return c;
}
int main(void){
    struct node *ss;
    ss = init_structure();
    printf("%d\n",ss->a);
}
```

Another way this could be accomplished is by adding another level of indirection:

```
void init_structure(struct node **c)
{
    **c=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    (*c)->a=1;
}
int main(void){
    struct node *ss;
    init_structure(&ss);
    printf("%d\n",ss->a);
}
```

This works, too, but is of course more cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the timely answer.But what i pass to the function is a pointer!!!Which means if i change the value of the pointer in function  init_struct.Then the value which the pointer points to will be changed too.This is what i comprehent.

Comment: @user2109469: You're changing the pointer itself, not the memory pointed to by the pointer. You could also pass the function a pointer to a pointer to the structure and modify the pointer pointed to by the pointer to change the value in `main`. Of course, you'd then have to take the address of `ss` when you call `init_structure`. Look at the second part of my updated answer to see that approach.